# Normal subgroup and index problem

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ of finite index. Show that if $H$ is a finite subgroup of $G$ whose order is coprime with $[G:N]$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $N$.

I don't know what to do in this exercise so I would appreciate hints and suggestions to have an idea of how could I solve it.

Comment: Think about the image of $H$ under the projection map $G\to G/N$.

Comment: Extremely useful comment. Let me see: pick an arbitrary element $\phi(h) \in im(H)$ and let $m=|H|$, then $e_{G/N}=\phi(e_G)=\phi(h^m)=\phi(h)^m$. But then, $|Im(H)|$ divides $|H|$. Since $|im(H)|$ also divides $|G/N|=[G:N]$, then $|im(H)|$ divides $gcm(m,[G:N])=1$. So $im(H)=e_{G/N}=N$,  this implies $H \leq ker(\phi)=N$.

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: Or, by the 2nd isomorphism theorem, $NH/N \cong H/(H \cap N)$, so $|H| = |H \cap N|[NH:N]$. Since $|H|$ is coprime to $[NH:N]$, it follows that $|H|$ must divide $|H \cap N|$. But $H\cap N \leq H$, so $|H \cap N| = |H|$. Therefore, $H \cap N = H$, and $H \leq N$.

Comment: Why $NH=G$? Or if that is not the case, why $|H|$ is coprime to $[NH:N]$?

Comment: No, $NH \leq G$. If $|H|$ had a factor in common with $[NH:N]$, then it would have a factor in common with $[G:NH][NH:N] = [G:N]$.

Answer (score 0):

$HN/N \cong H/(H\cap N)$. Hence the finite number $|HN/N|$ divides index$[G:N]=|G/N|$. But being equal to $|H/(H \cap N)|$ is also divides $|H|$. Since gcd($|G/N|,|H|)=1$, we must have $HN=N$, that is $H \subseteq N$.